# DateTime ToString() and TryParse()

Tags: .net, parsing, datetime, tostring

At first I do:

```
string stringDate = date.ToString(invariantCultureInfo);
```

Then:

```
DateTime.TryParse(stringDate, out date);
```

and it returns false. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: What does `stringDate` contain?

Comment: result of date.ToString. see edited

Comment: @DotNET Ninja, you're not trying to parse using the InvariantCulture - you're trying to use your current culture, that might be the problem.

Comment: As @Jackson Pope said, if you do not pass as third parameter the format string you used: invariantCultureInfo the TryParse method try to use your current culture or tries to discover the parse format. You'll obtain the true result using the same format: invariantCulturInfo for TryParse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DateTime.TryParse(stringDate, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date);
```

Answer (score 0):

`InvariantCulture` did not work for me. I took a `DateTime` from a SQL Server database and converted it to a string by using the `ToString()` method of the `DateTime` object. Then I attempted `DateTime.TryParse()` on that very same string and it failed. Further testing showed that `TryParse()` was failing because of the hyphen that `ToString()` inserts between the date element and the time element.